# Getting a chrome app on an Android phone without publishing the App

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have followed the instructions here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app to create my first Chrome App. Now I would like to test this app on my android smartphone.

Do I really need to follow the publishing instructions here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/publish_app, or can I simply copy a zip file over to the smartphone? I would guess this is possibly, since I was able to install the app in the chrome browser installed on my mac without having published it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on Android is different from chrome on a desktop. Just because an app can run on chrome for desktop, it cannot be run in the same way on android. Instead there are instructions for deploying a chrome app, that you may already have tested on the desktop, to a mobile device here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile (I could have found this earlier).

For preparing a chrome app for android a separate toolchain containing node.js, Java jdk, android sdk and apache ant are needed.